# how to unselect rows in excel filters

Tags: excel

Say I want to filter row related to Michael from the following excel spreadsheet

[image]

If I just use the usual excel filtering tool, than by selecting "Michael" I get the following result

[image]

But what I am looking for is a filter which never hides rows "number of children" and "social benefits" as follows

[image]

Anybody can provide me a good suggestion?

Comment: The only way I can think of right now is to re-arrange your data. Put rows 2-3 on top, your headers underneath followed by your data. You can achieve this also by selecting your data, apply a real table (no headers). This will push your data one row down, inserts headers which you can filter on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you could consider:

- Re-arrange your data structure
- Insert a listobject (table)
- Use `AdvancedFilter`

I'll demonstrate these options below, with the following sample data:

[image]

---

***Re-arrange your data structure:***

As per my comment, when you re-structure your data like the following:

[image]

You could simply apply the filter on the 3rd row and get the result you want.

---

***Insert a listobject (table)***

Technically almost the same thing as above, but you can insert a `Listobject`.

- Select your data > Ribbon > Insert > Table > No headers

This will push your data one row down and inserts auto-defined headers (change as you wish) and apply your filter.

[image]

---

***Use AdvancedFilter***

You might even want to re-arange your data a little bit and include your field as "criteria" in a filter. While I don't think that's possible through a normal filter (more than two), you can do so with `AdvancedFilter`.

- Apply a meaningfull header to your first column
- Insert 4 rows at the top
- Make sure the header corresponds to your first column header
- Type your criteria in the rows below and > Ribbon > Data > Advanced Filter

The result would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the filter arrow on the column header, then go to Text Filters > Custom Filter

[image]

Then you can use the drop-down menus and And/Or buttons to create your filter criteria.  This example will only return rows that *contain* the word Jetson or McFly.  You can make the table filter to the request in your question by choosing "Equals" then type your first option, click And, in the next line, choose "Equals" and add your next option, and so on.

[image]